# curl Request to Unverified Website

Tags: php

I am trying to use PHP's `curl()` function and for some reason my code does not return any data.

I am making a request to a URL that is unverified:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("**SENSITIVE URL**");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

If I put in `www.google.com` it does return the google webpage to my site. I apoligize, but I can't give out the URL for my site but **I assure you that directly going to the URL does return data**.

Comment: Try `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

Comment: This is the correct answer.  A quick google search would have netted the same as well.

Comment: No luck with that code. `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` yields no results still.

Comment: Have you tried to `echo curl_error($ch);`?  `$result` is probably `false` (try using `var_dump($result);` instead).

Comment: `SSL: certificate subject name 'ASAP' does not match target host name 'seldovia.asap.um.maine.edu'`

Comment: In that case, try to also add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell cURL to ignore the (bad) SSL cert.  Try adding the following options:

```
// Do not verify the cert
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// Ignore the "does not match target host name" error
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
```